# Draw each sector of a circle separately

Tags: java, opengl

I want to draw a circle using OpenGL, except I want each sector (18 in total) to be drawn as a separate shape so I can format each sector differently. How would I go about doing that?

Here is my attempt so far, which draws 18 sectors over each other[image]

```
int x = 480/2;
int y = (255/2)-15;
int r = 90;
int sectors = 90; //5x amount of actual sectors

GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glColor4f(0.6F, 0.6F, 0.6F, 0.3F);
    GL11.glBegin( GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );   
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            for(int n = 0; n <= sectors/18; n++)
            {
                float t = 2 * 3.14152f * (float)n / (float)sectors;
                GL11.glVertex2d(x + Math.sin(t) * r, y + Math.cos(t) * r);
            }
        }
    GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

This is for a Minecraft Forge mod.

Comment: That no circle. What is your code supposed to do, and what is your exact problem?

Comment: My code is supposed to make 18 sectors of a circle, and it is not. My problem is my lack of skills with maths. I've managed to figure it out now though, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Oh noes! glBegin(), i bet that's why the circle's not drawing... just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

```
                //Place circle slightly above centre of screen
            int x = 480 / 2;
            int y = (255 / 2) - 15;

            int r = 90;
            int sectors = 90; // Circle quality

            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glColor4f(0.6F, 0.6F, 0.6F, 0.3F);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
            for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
            {
                for(int n = 0+(i*5); n <= (sectors / 18) + (i*5); n++) //I just had to re-multiply the sectors to get up to 90 and carry on where the last sector left off.
                {
                    float t = 2 * 3.14152f * (float) n / (float) sectors;
                    GL11.glVertex2d(x + Math.sin(t) * r, y + Math.cos(t) * r);
                }
            }
            GL11.glEnd();
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
```